# Understanding how to update original 2D array from inside function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, variable-assignment

I understand how to pass a 2D array to a function in C, but I would like to have the function update the original structure rather than a copy of it. How would I go about this? Why does the method I use create a copy of the structure - I was under the impression it was another syntax equivalent to using a pointer?

Thanks for any help. I've included code snippets underneath:

**Declaring the variables**

```
int R[rowsize][colsize], G[rowsize][colsize], B[rowsize][colsize];
int Rnew[rowsize][colsize], Gnew[rowsize][colsize], Bnew[rowsize][colsize];
```

**Initialising the function**

```
void blur(int rowsize, int colsize, int R[][428], int G[][428], int B[][428], int Rnew[][428], int Gnew[][428], int Bnew[][428]){
. . .
}
```

NB: Within this function, `Rnew`, `Gnew` and `Bnew` should be updated - each are a 2D array. I would like this to be done *without* returning anything.

**Calling the function**

```
blur(rowsize, colsize, R, G, B, Rnew, Gnew, Bnew)
```

Comment: Are you sure it makes a copy?

Comment: A function parameter declared as `int R[][428]` is automatically adjusted to have the type “pointer to array of 428 `int`” ( that is, `int (*)[428]`). A function argument that is an array of type `int [][428]` is automatically converted to a pointer to the first element of that array (and, since it is an array of arrays, the first element is an array) and has type `int (*)[428]`. The result is that what is passed to the function is not an array but a pointer to its first element (an array). Changes made using that pointer will affect the original array.

Answer (score -2):

You may try this way..

```
# include <stdio.h>
#define rowsize 3
#define colsize 3
int main()
{
  int R[rowsize][colsize]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  int Rnew[rowsize][colsize];

  copy_from_R_to_Rnew(R,&Rnew);

  int i,j;

  for(i=0;i<rowsize;i++)
   {
     for(j=0;j<colsize;j++){

         printf("\t %d",Rnew[i][j]);
     }

     printf("\n");
   }
  return(0);
}

void copy_from_R_to_Rnew(int *R,int *Rnew)
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<rowsize;i++)
   {
     for(j=0;j<colsize;j++){
         *(Rnew+i*colsize+j) = *(R+i*colsize+j);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. It should give you several warnings when compiling, your types do not match. You are not passing `int` pointers to your function.